# Simultaneous Riemann mappings

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ by simply-connected polygons in the plane.
[Riemann's mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) implies that, for each individual polygon $C_i$, there is an analytic bijection $f_i$ that maps $C_i$ to any given *convex* polygon (e.g. the unit square).

Is there a *single* analytic bijection $f$ on the plane, that maps each $C_i$ to a convex polygon?

Comment: Your analytic bijections $f_i$ are very much *not* defined on the plane. A given $f_i$ is only defined on $C_i$ and is only analytic on its interior. Note that no holomorphic map of the plan can accomplish what you want, since if a linear map doesn't just do the job for you, by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions, your $f$ cannot map lines to lines.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks for the correction. What if one of the polygons, say $C_1$, contains all the others - is there an analytic bijection of $C_1$ that makes both $C_1$ and $C_2,\ldots,C_n$ convex?

Comment: Just like before, the identity theorem is the obstruction. Unless your polygons are all mapped to convex polygons by some linear map, you would have to look for an analytic map which doesn't map lines to lines in the interior of hte big polygon, but then the image of the other polygons cannot be a polygon.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I see, they cannot be polygons. But can they at least be convex?

Comment: @EretSegalHalevi That seems like a tall order to me. Know that the entire map is already more or less determined by whatever you want to map the largest polygon to.